# how to avoide duplicate entry in csv while woking with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to log success count and failure count in a CSV.
I am using Python Pandas for it.

Expectations:
All entries should be unique.
The email column should be unique and the success count or failure count should increase based on parameters,

Error:
I am getting duplicate entries in the CSV.
Multiple entries with the same email are present in the output CSV.

I am checking in my code if the email already exists in the entry.
Still, I am getting duplicate entries in the data.csv

**Edit:
Adding a complete code that reproduces the issues.**

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def save_data(email: str, is_success: int, is_failed: int) -> None:
    csv_file_path = "data.csv"

    # Check if the CSV file already exists and handle empty file case
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            columns=["email", "success_count", "failure_count", "last_updated_on"]
        )

    # Check for duplicates and update counts
    if email in df["email"].values:
        index = df[df["email"] == email].index[0]
        df.at[index, "failure_count"] += is_failed
        df.at[index, "success_count"] += is_success
        df.at[index, "last_updated_on"] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    else:
        # Append new entry
        new_entry = {
            "email": email,
            "success_count": is_success,
            "failure_count": is_failed,
            "last_updated_on": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        }
        df = df._append(new_entry, ignore_index=True)

    # Write to CSV file
    try:
        df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occurred while writing to CSV file:", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [
        ("123456", 1, 0),
        ("456789", 0, 1),
        ("789012", 1, 0),
        #
        ("123456", 0, 1),
        ("456789", 1, 0),
        ("789012", 0, 1),
    ]

    for data in arr:
        email, is_success, is_failed = data
        save_data(email=email, is_success=is_success, is_failed=is_failed)
```

Comment: what is `_append`? isn't it `append`?

Comment: `append` is giving a syntax error.  `_append` is working fine.

Comment: `append` is deprecated. It is recommended to use `concat()` now.

Comment: Please make a [mre] including complete code (i.e. show how the function is called), input data, desired output, and actual output for completeness. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: @OskarHofmann `concat()` is not exactly *recommended* since appending to a df is slow at scale no matter what method you use, but it's a workaround, and it's fine for small scale.

Comment: @OskarHofmann BTW, [`append` was actually removed in Pandas 2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

Comment: @wjandrea I have added the complete code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Don't use `df._append`, and no, `df.append` does not give you a syntax error. It.may not exist though depending on the version of pandas. You should use `pd.concat`

Comment: but when I am using `int` values in email column. duplicate entries are happening. 
but when I am using `string`. It is working fine. 
why?

Comment: @SoulDenied OK, looks good, now add the input/output

Comment: @wjandrea if you run the script. you can see duplicate entries in the data.csv file.

Comment: @SoulDenied Your code has `data.csv` as one of the possible inputs. If it's not needed to reproduce the issue, remove it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `pd.drop_duplicates()` to your dataframe at the end

You can specify further details using some parameters like `subset`, `keep`, etc.

Comment: I believe it is inefficient to add duplicate entries and then drop them at the end.

Comment: @SoulDenied, absolutely, but as a last resource, it will totally work.